# How to get a white background in XFCE terminal of Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, xfce, xfce4-terminal

I am using Xubuntu 16.04

The terminal background is black and my eyes are straining.

How can I make the terminal background white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve that is to load a different color-preset in the terminal-preferences.

[image]